# How to get pixel distance from two matched features

Tags: android, opencv

I am using Android OpenCV to detect features from the input frame of the camera. I am using the ORB feature detector and ORB descriptor extractor with BFMatcher. Now I got some matches Mat in the format of

```
matches = Mat [ 421*1*CV_32FC4, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x5fad7b30, dataAddr=0x5fab84f0 ]
```

I wonder what is the nativeObj and dataAddr represented for? I want to **get the distance between two matched features** in pixel, any idea?

I have found someone else had the same question and there was no reply. [How to Access Points location on OpenCV Matcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937490/how-to-access-points-location-on-opencv-matcher)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are performing match of descriptors of features you should get `MatOfDMatch`. Your code should be like this:

```
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2 ,matches);
```

After you can transform `MatOfDMatch` to the `List<DMatch>` for easier manipulation. You can do it with :

```
List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
```

Then you can access to the matched points and obtain the Cartesian coordinates with:

```
Point pt1 = keypoints1.toList().get(matchesList.get(i).queryIdx).pt; 
Point pt2 = keypoints2.toList().get(matchesList.get(i).trainIdx).pt;
```

After just calculate the distance between two points:

```
double dist_x_pow = Math.pow(Math.abs(pt1.x - pt2.x),2);
double dist_y_pow = Math.pow(Math.abs(pt1.y - pt2.y),2);
double DISTANCE = Math.sqrt(dist_x_pow + dist_y_pow);
```

About `nativeObj` and `dataAddr` I'm not sure, but I think it is related to the fact that OpenCV library is implemented in C and I think that this values represent address in memory of the Mat object.